# How do I split a string into a list of strings between opening and closing parentheses in c++?

Tags: c++, string, substring

I needed some help with a method on how to parse a string into multiple substrings. The form of the string may be (if (a = b) (a) (b)) or something similar with many opening and closing parentheses. For instance I need a list of strings such as,

element(0) = "(if (a = b) (a) (b))"

element(1) = "(a = b)",

element(2) = "(a)", and

element(3) = "(b)".

I have already tried going through the string by each individual character using String.at() and counting the opening and closing parentheses. However this gets very tricky, and I don't believe its the most efficient or easy way to do this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can be very easily done recursively. Just go through your string, if you hit a `(`, recurse to parse the substring from the place where you found the `(`. If you hit a `)`, you've found the end of a substring and can return the start and end…

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Verifiable, and Complete Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can start from simple algorithm with stack:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <deque>

std::deque<std::string> parse(const std::string &str)
{
    std::deque<std::string> result;
    std::stack<std::string::const_iterator> stack;
    for ( auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end();) {
        if (*it == '(') {
            stack.push(it++);
        } else if (*it == ')') {
            auto start = stack.top(); stack.pop();
            result.push_back(std::string{start, ++it});
        } else {
            it++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int , char **) {
    std::string input = "(if (a = b) (a) (b))";
    auto output = parse(input);
    for(const  auto & s:output) {
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to add check if stack underflows

Or, if you want to preserve exact order as in question, use `std::map<std::size_t, std::deque<std::string>>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <map>

std::deque<std::string> parse(const std::string &str)
{
    std::map<std::size_t, std::deque<std::string>> map;
    std::stack<std::string::const_iterator> stack;
    for ( auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end();) {
        if (*it == '(') {
            stack.push(it++);
        } else if (*it == ')') {
            auto start = stack.top(); stack.pop();
            map[stack.size()].push_back(std::string{start, ++it});
        } else {
            it++;
        }
    }
    std::deque<std::string> result;
    for (const auto & p : map) {
        for (const auto & s : p.second) {
            result.push_back(s);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int , char **) {
    std::string input = "(if (a = b) (a) (b))";
    auto output = parse(input);
    for(const  auto & s:output) {
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you! This perfectly answered my questions and cleared up some things about C++ as well. It's my first time using C++, instead of C, Java, or Swift. So thank you for your help!

Comment: @Lucas you can see sources also here https://github.com/kelebdil/study/blob/master/brackets/main.cpp